# Migrating Oracle indexes to HP Vertica projections

Tags: oracle, database-migration, projection, vertica, database-indexes

I'm not really good at Vertica. Please help me in general understanding of how to find the closest projection equivalent in HP Vertica that reflects Oracle index in each particular case. 
Provided, I have the following table in Oracle

```
create table new_customers(CustomerId number(10,0), Name varchar2(50), Age number(3,0), State char(2), Address varchar2(50), DateOfBirth date);
```

And the following indexes:

```
create unique index new_customers_idx1 on new_customers(CustomerId);

create index new_customers_idx3 on new_customers(name,age desc);

create index new_customers_idx4 on new_customers(extract(month from DateOfBirth));
```

The version of HP Vertica server that I use for testing is 7.0

1) So the 1-st projection will look as follows, right?

```
create projection new_customers_idx1
as
select * from new_customers 
ORDER BY CustomerId;
```

2) In the 2-nd one I guess there's no way to implement descending sort functionality as according to documentation projections store records in ascending order only.

```
create projection new_customers_idx3
as
select * from new_customers 
ORDER BY Name,Age;
```

Or probably in this case there's no point in creating projection at all?

3) The 3-rd projection is of major question. As there're examples of using expressions and even functions is projection's select list:

> https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/Projections/ProjectionsWithExpressions.htm

However I'm not able to create projection like this:

```
create projection new_customers_idx4 AS
select CustomerId,
Name,
Age,
State,
Address,
DateOfBirth,
month(DateOfBirth) as ColAl 
from new_customers 
ORDER BY ColAl;
```

ERROR 4241:  Only columns are allowed in SELECT list of projection

Please give me the overall hint on implementing indexes functional through projections, and is there any way of creating projection corresponding to function-based index?

Comment: - forget about the index concept as you know it from Oracle, understand segmentation, join key user, order by in projections, access ranks. See Kermit links, they will bring light :)

Answer (score 1):

Projection != Index

You do not create a projection just because there was an index on your OLTP database. These are two completely different concepts.

I encourage reading this three part series on what projections are and the comparison/contrast from materialized views and indexes.

- [Projection Overview 1](https://www.vertica.com/2011/09/01/the-power-of-projections-part-1/)
- [Projection Overview 2](http://www.vertica.com/2011/09/02/the-power-of-projections-part-2/)
- [Projection Overview 3](https://www.vertica.com/2011/09/06/the-power-of-projections-part-3/)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, Vertica projections are not at all equivalent to Oracle (or other row-organized database system) indexes, because the data access methods used by Vertica are entirely different.

You would need to look at your queries to determine the projections that might be useful, rather than build projections for all your Oracle indexes.

Your first suggested projection is completely redundant, as it is essentially identical to the table's superprojection, which is by default sorted by the columns in the order they are defined.

The second suggested projection will only be useful if you routinely run queries that `GROUP BY name`, for example; it's unlikely that it will make much difference for queries like `WHERE name = ?`.

I suggest you start with simply creating your tables, loading some meaningful sample data, and running the [Vertica Database Designer](http://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/ConfiguringTheDB/PhysicalSchema/DesigningAPhysicalSchema.htm%3FTocPath%3DAdministrator%27s%20Guide%7CConfiguring%20the%20Database%7CCreating%20a%20Database%20Design%7C_____0) tool to determine if any additional projections might be useful.